# Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. Even after using hooks guidlines

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-dom

I am trying to use hooks inside the functional component. Just defining the hook itself I am getting an error.

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

function CreateTemplate() {
  const editorRef = useRef();
  return (<div>something</div>)
}
```

And this file is called on click of the previous component, where history is used. Adding it to the

```
<button
    onClick={() => {
        history.push({
          pathname: "/create-template",
        });
      }}
    >
      CONFIRM TEMPLATE
</button>
```

And Route is defined below.

```
  <Switch>
    <AuthRoute path='/dashboard' render={Dashboard} type='private' />
    <AuthRoute path='/templates' render={Templates} type='private' />
    <AuthRoute
      path='/create-template'
      render={CreateTemplate}
      type='private'
    />
    <Route path='/' render={Dashboard} />
  </Switch>
```

Below is the react and react-dom version

```
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2"
```

I am not sure why useRef hook or any hook throwing above error. Tried almost all possible solution.

Comment: could you please add error snippet over here

Comment: Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem

Comment: try to  `const editorRef  = useRef(null);`

Comment: Please share the `AuthRoute` component as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely not rendering `CreateTemplate` correctly in the route, a `render` prop typically takes a function value. Depending on your `AuthRoute` implementation I believe you can do one of the following:

Use the `component` prop:

```
<AuthRoute
  path='/create-template'
  component={CreateTemplate}
  type='private'
/>
```

Keep the `render` prop and render an anonymous component:

```
<AuthRoute
  path='/create-template'
  render={routeProps => <CreateTemplate {...routeProps} />}
  type='private'
/>
```

If neither of these are the case then surely we'll need to see your `AuthRoute` component implementation to see how it's rendering.

Comment: It worked, can you please explain what is "routeProps" and why do we need to use here

Comment: @rajm [Route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) are the `history`, `location`, and `match` props provided by a `Route` component, and I assumed, by syntax, you were using react-router/react-router-dom. The [render prop function](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func) has access to all the same route props (match, location and history) as the component render prop. You don't *need* to pass the route props through, but it's a good habit to be in to start with them.